# How can I show traditional paragraph mark and line break mark in Microsfot Word 2016?

Tags: microsoft-word

It seems that Microsoft Word 2016 doesn't show paragrah mark by default.

There are articals saying that I can turn it on by checking the box of File -> Options -> Display -> Paragraph marks.

I can do it by clicking the button in Home -> Paragraph, too:
[image]

But it shows:

[image] for paragrah

[image] for line break

Neither of them is traditional paragraph mark. What I want is something like:

[image]for paragrah

[image]for line break

These two symbols are used in old Microsoft Word, for example Word 97, Word 2000, etc.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to customise how to display those characters

Comment: I don’t think the previous paragraph mark and line break mark could not be used back, this is an intentional behavior change of Microsoft.

Comment: You are mistaken, at least in the English-language versions. The current marks have been the marks since at least Word 97. There is no option available to change them. I barely used Word 95 or Word for DOS so cannot speak to that.

Answer (score -1):

Change (or add) the default editing language in settings to a language other than English, then you should get the symbols you mentioned. However I am using the Word 2016 with non-English display language too. I am not sure if display language also affect this.

Symbols 1

[image]

Symbols 2

[image]